# Traversing the hash of hash of array

Tags: perl

Here is by code :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my $var = { 
    Cars => {
        cars_name => [
            "GT500", 
            "Beetle",
            "P1800"
        ]
    },           
    Bikes => {
        Bikes_name => [
            "Pulsar",
            "Discover",
            "CBR"
        ]
    }
};

#Traversing the hash of hash of array
print "$var\n";
foreach my $k1 (keys %{$var}) {

    print "$k1\n";
    print $var->$k1;
    #foreach my $k2 (keys %{$var->$k1}) {

         #print"$k2\n";
    #}   
}
```

Whenever i am trying to print cars_name and Bikes_name , i am getting an **error message saying the Can't call method Cars on Unblessed reference.** I am not able to figure it out where am i doing mistake. Well, by mine understanding  this `print $var->$k1`; line creating a prob. So please can any body help me out of this.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 print $var->$k1;
```

that is calling a method on an object. You want to access a hash:

```
 print $var->{$k1};
```